# Restructuring existing Web API - should I use OAuth?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

Most articles on MVC WebAPI OAuth assume there is some resource owner (like a person) who will authorize the release of data. In our case the data is public, like product for sale, or name of departments etc. The API just hides unnecessary/malicious access to things like date created, activity user etc. - and of course saves the front end developer from learning database schema.

Does OAuth fit in this scenario where no particular owner exists?

Answer (score 0):

> Does OAuth fit in this scenario where no particular owner exists?

Yes it does.

Sure, the primary focus of the OAuth specification is to protect resoures owned by the resource owner, but it can of course protect other resources too. Take Facebook for example: it protects not only *your* data, but also the data of your friends, which is accessible by you.

In your case, you need to protect those fields, and OAuth is a good mechanism for users with the necessary rights to authorize an application to access those fields. Users without the necessary rights (if those are registered users at all) would of course not be able to do so.

In addition, there usually is one resource that is owned by the user: the user's profile data.

OAuth 2.0 is the best protocol available today to secure a web API.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow anyone (= any client application) to access your APIs without any restriction, you don't have to care about OAuth.

On the other hand, if you want to allow accesses only from client applications that have been registered in advance, "[Client Credentials Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)" in RFC 6749 (OAuth 2.0) is probably the best for you. The flow does not associate an access token with any specific resource owner. An access token is issued based on only the client credentials (= client ID and client secret) of a client application.